# Tkinter: refresh frame/window from an outside function

Tags: python, tkinter, reload

I would like to refresh the `MainPage` when the `updateCustomerList` is finished updating the list so that this updated list is shown on the `MainPage` widgets.

I tried playing around with `tk.show_frame(<frame>)` and etc. but since the function itself isn't tied to the main Tkinter frame itself or isn't even a Tkinter object, then I'm not entirely sure how to reload the page. Any suggestions?

The code below is a snippet of my entire program:

```
customerList = [] #list is updated at the updateCustomerList function; global variable

class POS(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (ErrorPage, PaymentPage, MainPage): 
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        #show frame here


class MainPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        """
        Tkinter frame that I would like to "refresh" and use the new updated list
        """
        frame5Button = ttk.Button(frame5, text = "Add Item", command = lambda: updateCustomerList(barCode, quantity))
        frame5Button.grid(row = 0, column = 5, padx = 90, pady = 10)
        #This button allows me to go into the updateCustomerList function

def updateCustomerList(barCode, quantity):
    #some code to update a list
    #when function finishes updating the list, I would like to go back to the MainPage Tk frame and reload all the widgets like labels and entry boxes using the updated customerList list

app = POS()
app.geometry("700x700") 
app.resizable(False, False)
app.after(100, MasterFilePopUp)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The indentation in your code is borked (see the `for F ...` loop)

Comment: fixed! Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove and recreate the instance of `Mainframe` inside as the last line of `updateCustomerList`:

```
container = 0 #global variable
```

Add "global container" inside POS(tk.Tk)

```
def updateCustomerList(barCode, quantity):
    global app
    ...
    app.frames[MainPage].destroy()
    app.frames[MainPage] = MainPage(container, app)
    app.frames[MainPage].grid(row=0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
    app.frames[MainPage].tkraise() 
#function ends here
```

Comment: It is not created in a global scope. It is created locally inside the POS() class, or at least that's from my understanding. Nonetheless, I'll give it a try!

Comment: How exactly is it created in `POS` then?

Comment: Updated the code posted above to show how I created my frames

Comment: @Miggy Updated my answer.

Comment: I think it should work but I still need to work out some kinks. Will be back when I get it going. Thank you!

Comment: As of the moment, it keeps on refreshing to PaymentPage from the frames[] list. I've also changed your code to use app instead of pos. Any ideas on why the PaymentPage runs instead of MainPage?

Comment: @Miggy Are you certain you're showing `MainPage` and not `PaymentPage`?

Comment: Yeah, should be. I updated the code a little bit more to show my changes.

Comment: @Miggy You need to separately call show method again, see the update.

Comment: @ Nae I think the problem is that my parent and controller aren't global. I've also made the changes but it still has the same problem

Comment: @ Nae yep, the global parent/controller was the problem. Fixed it! Thank you